# vb6 data report shows designer at runtime

Tags: vb6, report, designer

I'm developing an app in VB6 and added a data report bound to a data environment. I set the report as start up object, but it shows the designer and not the report viewer!

I have built a new project and imported all of the objects back in but to no avail.

I did a test with a small Data Project and it worked.

Has anyone else come across this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Problem allayed due to the fact that SHAPE commands cannot be used with DISCONNECTED recordsets...which defeats what I am trying to achieve here.

I'll use MSAccess reports via OLE server.

Thanks for looking anyway!